# couchdb public access - start failures eaddrnotavail

Tags: firewall, fedora, couchdb

If I start the couchdb service it fails and with journalctl-xe i can see the following:

`start request repeated too quickly for couchdb.service`

And when i do `couchdb -i` i get the following error:

`Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrnotavail`

In the file /etc/couchdb/local.ini i uncommented these line and change them to:

```
bind_address = 211.121.31.39  // is the ip from whatsmyip
port = 5984
```

In the firewall in the `zone public` i did:

- added port `5984 tcp and 5984 udp`
- and also checked the services `http and https`

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right way...

You have to set in the local.ini your local ip which you can get with ipconfig on windows or ifconfig in linux.

Then in the nat menu from your router add a routing entry to your local ip.

Now when you enter in the browser your public ip 211.121.x.x it goes to the router and then the router knows oh i have to forward this request to the pc with the local ip 192.168.x.x

maybe it helps someone else too.